# Why Tinymce get content retrieves wrong code?

Tags: javafx, tinymce, emoji, tinymce-plugins, javafx-webview

When I add **emoji** as follows
`<span lang=EN-US style='font-family:"Segoe UI Emoji",sans-serif;mso-fareast-language:EN-US'>&#128521;</span>`
into Tinymce 5 editor, it displays as usual, but when I save the content to the database, `editor.getContent` retrieves wrong code as below.

```
<p><span lang="EN-US" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji',sans-serif; mso-fareast-language: EN-US;">ߘ</span></p>
```

When I look at database I see it has been saved as `??` and when I open it with Tinymce again it display as `??` .
It seams Tinymce `getContent` could not retrieves `&#128521;` in the correct way.

I use `Javafx webView` as wrapper to display `Tinymce`.

**Anyone has any idea why, and how can we fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `entity_encoding: "numeric"` , inside Tinymce configuration.

Characters will be converted into numeric entities.
For example, a `non-breaking space` would be encoded as `&#160;`.

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: 'editor',
   width:'100%',
   height: '100%',
   entity_encoding: "numeric",
   plugins: 'print preview paste,...
```